# NullpointerException in export CSV when I changed environment to another Apache Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, nullpointerexception, struts-1

In test environment my app work fine and the export work but when I deploy my app in another environment (PROD). In the beginning it was working after that we needed to restart server sometimes to get the export and now it doesn't work whatever we do.

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ma.euro.alert.srv.is.ListeGroupeAlerteIS.select(Unknown Source)
    at ma.euro.alert.ihm.action.PlanningAction.actionChoixRrc(Unknown Source)
    at ma.euro.alert.ihm.action.PlanningAction.executeInt(Unknown Source)
    at ma.web.FrmWebLgc.execute(Unknown Source)
    at ma.web.StdWebLgc.perform(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.processActionPerform(ActionServlet.java:1787)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1586)
    at ma.web.StdWebCnt.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:510)
    at ma.web.StdWebCnt.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at ma.euro.alert.ihm.GestAlertActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:760)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:356)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.processActionForward(ActionServlet.java:1759)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1596)
    at ma.web.StdWebCnt.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:510)
    at ma.web.StdWebCnt.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at ma.euro.alert.ihm.GestAlertActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:760)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:247)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:643)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:480)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:995)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:643)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:480)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:995)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.invoke(StandardContext.java:2417)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:643)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorDispatcherValve.invoke(ErrorDispatcherValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:480)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:995)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:643)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:480)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:995)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat4.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:193)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:309)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:387)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:673)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:615)
    at org.apache.jk.common.SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:786)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:666)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: show us the code ...

Comment: it's normal to have (Unknown Source) in my source code on the trace of the exeption ???

Comment: I think you did compile without debug information

Comment: wanna see this: `at ma.euro.alert.srv.is.ListeGroupeAlerteIS.select`

Comment: It is because you got `NPE` somewhere...

Comment: @Antoniossss : but i tell u it's working in my environment without blems and in the beginning it's worked on this environment too.

Comment: @ACV : it's normal to have unKnown source in all my line code on the trace ?

Comment: it's normal if it was intended to be so, if you provided some special flags to ant or maven. Some other reason could be JAVA_OPTS coniguration. Check it in Environment Variables. It also sometimes happens when I redeploy the application in eclipse, but without restarting tomcat

Comment: @ACV : thanks i ll try this.